# Custom terms inserting as single string with commas, not separated

Tags: wp-insert-post, terms

I have a front end form, one of the inputs asks for a comma separated list of keywords which should each end up being a custom term, I just saw in the backend the terms are entered as single string with the commas and not individually.

My code is below, how can I turn the string ie; term1,term2,term3 which may be entered in the input to 'term1','term2','term3' which is what the format looks like it needs to be to insert each keyword as a unique term?

I've tried both with `wp_insert_post` and `wp_set_object_terms`

```
$keywords = $_POST['keywords'];

$new_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'tax_input'    => array( 'keyword' => array( $keywords ) ),
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'test'
);

$nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
 if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'form-nonce' ) ) {
     die( 'Security check' ); 
 } else {
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    //var_dump($new_post);

    //wp_set_object_terms($pid,$keywords,'keyword');
 }
    wp_redirect( get_permalink($pid) ); 
    //echo $pid;
    exit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make an array from comma separated string of keywords like

```
$keywords = explode(',', $keywords);
```

then your insert post data array will be.

```
$new_post = array(
  'post_title'    => $title,
  'tax_input'    => array( 'keyword' => $keywords ),
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_type' => 'test'
);
```